# Add new user active directory

Tags: c#, active-directory

I get this error

> "the server is unwilling to process this request"

when I want to add user in active directory
source code:

```
public static void SubmitUser(string OU, string username, string password, bool enabled, 
        string givenName)
    {
        using (PrincipalContext ctx = GetPrincipalContext(OU))
        {

            UserPrincipalEx user = UserPrincipalEx.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, username);
            if (user == null)
            {

                user = new UserPrincipalEx(ctx);
                user.SamAccountName = username;
                user.SetPassword(password);

            }
            user.Enabled = enabled;


            //if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(username) && user.SamAccountName != username)
            //{
            //    user.SamAccountName = username;
            //}

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(givenName) && user.GivenName != givenName)
            {
                user.GivenName = givenName;
            }
```

Comment: Does the account have permission to create user?

Comment: have you tried to call user.CommitChanges() ?

Comment: At which line you are getting error?